# how to this database schema?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

design  the Database  schema  for  shipment company based on the following requirement with its constraints that maintains the data integrity , and write the SQL command for that .
•   The shipment system  contain information about the suppliers, items, shipments  as follows : 
Supplier name with maximum 100 character , not allowed to have more than supplier, supplier name should not be  left empty and the name must not be repeated.
Supplier number   must not repeated for each supplier ,The nationality of the supplier almost is Jordanian and the Jewish nationality not allowed to deal with.

The shipment system contain information about the items as follow:
Item number which will not exceed the 99  items and this item number will not repeated for each item ,item name should  not  be repeated and  should not be empty, the total available quantity of this item in the store which must be 0 if the  user does not enter the initial quantity.

Each supplier could supply us with one item or more, which  is necessary to know the items for each supplier and the starting dealing date for supplying  the item. The item could be supplied  from more than one supplier .

The shipment system register the important  transaction information about the quantity of items that  supplied by the supplier with the shipment date  for each transaction .  each shipment transaction could have more than one item. ??

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: no this exercise in book i learn from it

Comment: Do you own homework and or post what you have done so far.

Comment: It is best to show an advance and put questions on specific problems.

Comment: Learn/Read about basic principals of Database design and then try to do it yourself, Unless you know what to keep in mind when designing a database you wont have any idea what and why people recommend you here :)

Comment: i need slove this to comper it with my work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First pick out the nouns.

```
Shipment, Item, Supplier, Nationality
```

These are your entities, then find attributes of these entities e.g.

```
Item :: Number, Name, Supplier
```

Pay attention to the attribute domain, you will probably want to constrain to these.

Work out how these entities relate e.g.

```
Item (m:n) Supplier
```

For many to many relationships normalize with junction tables.

Go over an pick out business constraints e.g.

```
Jordanians and Jews cannot trade with each other
```

these may require triggers to implement.

Comment: thanks , but how many tables I entered ??